# Prove that if $ \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \cdot \sin(1/x) = 0 $

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

This is the Problem 21 from Chapter 5 of M. Spivak's "Calculus". It states:

> Prove that if $ \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \cdot \sin(1/x)  = 0 $

That's how I approached the problem. First, we know that $\sin(1/x)$ does not approach any limit as $x$ approaches $0$. However, we also have that $ \left | \sin(1/x)  \right | \leq 1 = M $ for all $x$ near $0$.

Since $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$, we can make $g(x) \cdot sin1/x$ as close to zero as we want.
I am not sure how to prove this formally though. That's what I've come up with so far.

Since $M = 1$, we can have $ |g(x) \cdot M|  < \epsilon $ for any $\epsilon$. Thus, $|g(x)| < \dfrac {\epsilon}{|M|} = \epsilon $. However, I am stuck in converting this into statements about $\delta$ and generalizing for $M$ other than $1$. Need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$-g(x)\le g(x)\sin\frac1{x}\le g(x)$$
for all $x\ne 0$. Note that $$\pm g(x)\to 0\text{ as }x\to 0.$$ Therefore, by [the pinching theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), we have
$$g(x)\sin\frac1{x}\to 0\text{ as }x\to 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, that exercise about limits of f(x)<=g(x)<=h(x) was actually in the Problem 13 of Chapter 5 but I skipped it :(

Answer (score 0):

For $\epsilon>0$ we need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)\sin \frac{1}{x}-0|< \epsilon$ for all $0<|x|<\delta$. $$\left|g(x)\sin \frac{1}{x}\right|< |g(x)|$$

As $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=0 \implies \exists \delta>0$ for the same $\epsilon$ such that $|g(x)|< \epsilon$  for $0<|x|<\delta$ Hence $$\left|g(x)\sin \frac{1}{x}\right|< |g(x)|<\epsilon$$ for the same $\delta$.

Edit for strict inequality

Comment: We need find a $\delta$ such that $|g(x)\sin(1/x)|\le \epsilon$ as per the definition of limits of functions. As we have already chosen $\epsilon>0$, and the functions are defined we can estimate this.

Comment: Yes, but everywhere in the book it is written: ' f(x) approaches the limit L near a if for any E > 0, there is a D > 0 such that, for all x if 0<|x-a|<D, then |f(x)-L|<E." Thus I was confused by the <= sign.

Comment: You are right. Technically, its the open balls (open interval) we consider.